# How to grant project permissions to new users/groups?

Tags: permissions, sonarqube

I have SonarQube 6.4 installed and I created few projects. How to grant a user/group for a private project? When I go to Project Administration Permissions (where I can switch a project between public and private), it only shows sonar-administrators group. Where can I add a group for this project?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming your users and groups already exist: search for them. By default, this interface shows entities that already have permissions. To add more, just search for the missing entities by name. They'll show up in the interface and you can toggle the boxes to grant them permissions.